# Java Signature.verify results in SignatureException: Signature encoding error Caused by IOException: Sequence tag error

Tags: java, cryptography, smartcard

first of all this is not a duplicate question as most people  report this exception when creating a Public Key from a Certificate which is missing "---BEGIN RSA CERTIFICATE---" line.

gist of what I am trying to do is 
1. Sign a 50Byte message on JCOP Smart card using SHA1withRSA algorithm (RSA Key is 1024 bits).
2. Export the signature from smart card to server.
3. Verify the signature on the server.

Code snippet on the smart card to create the signature. The key point is I am using algorithm Signature.ALG_RSA_SHA_PKCS1 in the Java Card to create the signature.

```
private void setcustccid(APDU apdu) {

    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] != (byte)24) {
      ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
    }
    else {
      short bytesLeft = (short) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] & 0x00FF);
      short readCount = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
      if (readCount < bytesLeft) {
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_BYTES_REMAINING_00);
      }
      try {
                  Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_RSA_SHA_PKCS1, false);
        signature.init(privKey, Signature.MODE_SIGN);
        Util.arrayCopy(buffer, (short)buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA], tempStorage, (short) 0, (byte)24);
        Util.arrayCopy(transactionHistory, (short)0, tempStorage, (short)24, (byte)30);
      } 
      catch (Exception ex) {
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_BYTES_REMAINING_00);
      }

      signature.sign(tempStorage, (short)0, (short)50, finalEncryptedMsg, (short)0);
    }
    }
```

Code snippet on the Server side trying to verify the signature exported from the Java Smart card which is throwing the exception. The key point here is I am using Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA") on the server side. I am doing Cipher decrypt of the signed message just to confirm that the public key generated is working and it is.

```
modulusString = new BigInteger(1, rsaModulus);
exponentString = new BigInteger(1, rsaExponent);
RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulusString, exponentString);
KeyFactory factor = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 
PublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) factor.generatePublic(keySpec);
rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.update(resultBytes);
signature.verify(finalEncryptedMsg);
tempStorage = rsaCipher.doFinal(finalEncryptedMsg);
System.out.println("Decrypted Length = " + tempStorage.length);
```

The exception happens on signature.verify(). Another thread referred to this same exception but the solution was to add Bouncy Castle as the Provider in Signature.getInstance(). Not sure why Bouncy Castle would be required for verification of signature.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more of the code to identify the issue please let me know.

```
java.security.SignatureException: Signature encoding error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.mse.reader.SmartCardReader.main(SmartCardReader.java:234)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sequence tag error
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getSequence(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.decodeSignature(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Here is the Encrypted Msg and Decrypted Msg. (Base4.encodeBase64)

Encrypted Length = 128

```
JpypH/vKYR4RLjQA4frCab5WljnAoWgNiGUb0k+DCmh8gdWbOtpR/XUec2rW96Nr1k7czNTb2s/2WQDGXe05a3JjNrlErrfijhdWvn9flIzR/5uPrS3VJw+ALESl8NWqR5HF3AgArE6uYIW87EtSjO0iPJTO2N0cITtLghdUSBs=
```

Decrypted Length = 50

```
gCUAABgAAAAAO5rJkAAAAAAAvGFOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
```

Comment: Could you show in hex the result of the decrypt? I mean, modular exponentiation usually is successful, but the result may not be correct. Also show the signature input in hex. Bouncy is not required for this. Please specify `"RSA/ECB/NoPadding"` for the decryption instead of just `"RSA"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've moved your smart card provider in front of the other providers on Java SE, and for some reason it is also trying to verify RSA signatures instead of just using it for RSA private key operations.

There are a few methods of solving this:

1. if you are using the same signature instance for verification, then use a different one for the verification with the public key
2. if that doesn't solve your problem, try and see if you can move the smart card provider down in the list of providers in the `Security` class (check the [JCA documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Provider) on how to do this)
3. otherwise simply provide the correct provider using the `Signature` class, I would recommend specifying `"SunRsaSign"` (you may want to make this string configurable)
4. explain to the company behind `com.mse` that they should implement *delayed provider selection* correctly and not gobble up software public keys for use in their hardware device

Note that talking about "server side" is very confusing as the smart card acts as a server. "Terminal side" and "card side" would be a much more clear.

Comment: Thanks owlstead for the response. However I still dont understand the issue entirely. On the JCOP Card, I have no control to specify the Provider. Thats why I wasnt sure what you meant by "move the smart card provider down in the list of providers".  I tried specifying SunRsaSign as the provider on the server side but that didnt help.

Comment: With "didn't help" do you mean you still get the same error message or is it changed. Providers are only present in Java SE not Java Card. Please try option 3 and display the exception message. It would be very strange if it is the same one.

Comment: For this it is required that the public key is indeed generated by the software. Currently the exception is not in line with the code you've presented.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the Key Pair is generated on the card and I export the Public Key Modulus to the Terminal. I regenerate the Public Key on the terminal side using the modulus and exponent.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the Key Pair is generated on the card and I export the Public Key Modulus to the Terminal. I regenerate the Public Key on the terminal side using the modulus and exponent.   To try your suggestion, I generated a diff RSA Key Pair on terminal side and used that public Key to init the Signature and I am not getting the exception (but ofcourse the verify returns false as msg was signed with different key pair generated card side). I would like to keep the Key generation on the Card. Is there a work around. Thanks again.

Comment: Here is my code on the card side to generate the key pairs. code rsaKeyPair = new KeyPair( KeyPair.ALG_RSA_CRT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_1024); rsaKeyPair.genKeyPair(); privKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) rsaKeyPair.getPrivate(); pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyPair.getPublic(); signature = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_RSA_SHA_PKCS1, false); code

Comment: For some reason the signature retrieved in the card is incorrect, but even then you should not get any exception like the one you've shown in the question.

Comment: Can I send you the entire class file for Client and Terminal side, if it will help. Thanks

Comment: You could post those as links to some kind of online file service. That's OK for additional data for the question. Please include the links in the question, not below the answer.