# PKCS11 Verifying signature error: Signature encoding error Caused Sequence tag error

Tags: java, security, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm trying to verify the signature of a document, but I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.SignatureException: Signature
>   encoding error    at
>   sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:204)     at
>   java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1219)    at
>   java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:652)    at
>   VerSign.VerSign.main(VerSign.java:78)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sequence tag error    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getSequence(DerInputStream.java:297)
>     at
>   sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.decodeSignature(RSASignature.java:229)
>     at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:195)
>     ... 3 more

I'm using a smartcard with SUNPKCS11 provider.

-- Sign --

```
String configName = "/media/sf_Share_SI_Mint/conf";
Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);
Security.addProvider(p); 
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",p);  
ks.load(null,null);
String assinaturaCertifLabel = "CITIZEN SIGNATURE CERTIFICATE";
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(assinaturaCertifLabel, null);
Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(assinaturaCertifLabel);

byte[] sig = signDocument((PrivateKey)pk,p);

FileOutputStream sigfos = new FileOutputStream("sig");
sigfos.write(sig);
sigfos.close();

byte[] certificado = cert.getEncoded();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("cert");
fos.write(certificado);
fos.close();

private static byte[] signDocument(PrivateKey privateKey, Provider p) throws GeneralSecurityException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

            Signature signatureAlgorithm = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", p);
            signatureAlgorithm.initSign(privateKey);
            FileInputStream fich = new FileInputStream("Documento");
            byte[] doc = new byte[fich.available()];
            fich.read(doc); 
            signatureAlgorithm.update(doc);           
            byte[] digitalSignature = signatureAlgorithm.sign();

            return digitalSignature;


}
```

-- Verify --

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
FileInputStream certfis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(certfis);
certfis.close();

PublicKey pubKey = cert.getPublicKey();

FileInputStream sigfis = new FileInputStream(args[1]);
byte[] sigToVerify = new byte[sigfis.available()]; 
sigfis.read(sigToVerify);
sigfis.close();

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sig.initVerify(pubKey);

FileInputStream datafis = new FileInputStream(args[2]);
byte[] doc = new byte[datafis.available()];
datafis.read(doc);
sig.update(doc);
datafis.close();

boolean verifies = sig.verify(sigToVerify);
System.out.println("signature verifies: " + verifies);
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but this might be a duplicate: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053117/java-signature-verify-results-in-signatureexception-signature-encoding-error-ca

Comment: it's not a duplicate. Provider is different and the solutions didn't work at all.

Comment: Did you try to verify the signature using another tool (e.g. [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/rsautl.html) with `-hexdump` and with/without `-asn1parse` option. You should be able to find the SHA256 hash of the signed file contents in the output (AFAIK at the end)). Good luck!