# RSA java signature verification failed

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature

this might be a possible duplicate of:
[Java Signature.verify results in SignatureException: Signature encoding error Caused by IOException: Sequence tag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053117/java-signature-verify-results-in-signatureexception-signature-encoding-error-ca)
, but the answer did not answer my question.

Have this code:

```
String RSA_CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
String RSA_KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
String RSA_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA512withRSA";

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA_KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
RSAPublicKey key = (RSAPublicKey)keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(RSA_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
signature.initVerify(key);
signature.update(data);
```

Have this error:

```
java.security.SignatureException: Signature encoding error
at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:204)
at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1219)
at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:652)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sequence tag error
at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getSequence(DerInputStream.java:297)
at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.decodeSignature(RSASignature.java:229)
at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:195)
... 45 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when you have a signature that does contain [PKCS#1 compatible padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-9.2) (step 4 & 5) , but it doesn't contain the DER encoded identifier of the hash method used. This encoded identifier starts with a DER tag representing an ASN.1 SEQUENCE (step 1 & 2).

You can look at the encoding by using a raw RSA cipher:

```
// setup
Signature sigAlg = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");
sigAlg.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
byte[] signature = sigAlg.sign();

// check padding manually
Cipher rsaRaw = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
// encrypt or decrypt is actually the same operation for raw RSA
rsaRaw.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
byte[] paddedSig = rsaRaw.doFinal(signature);
// using Bouncy Castle's hex encoder, you can use any encoder
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(paddedSig));
```

Then you can actually see the sequence byte (value `30`, after a whole lot of `FF` bytes (the padding) and a single byte valued `00`. In case it *is* a valid signature of course:

```
0001ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff003051300d060960864801650304020305000440cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e
```

You'll probably just get 64 bytes that represent the hash value instead.

Comment: And what can I do with incoming signature to make it work?

Comment: Kick the person that sent you the signature, and let him use a **valid and correct** signature format. Or if they persist in sending you incorrect values: use `"RSA/ECB/NoPadding"` and extract the hash value yourself. Then compare with the computed hash.